# Highcharts x-range series. How to crop label inside data?

Tags: highcharts

I want to crop label inside the box of data in x-range chart when it overflows. How can I do it?

Code of the point:

```
{
    x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
    x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
    y: 2,
    dataLabels:[{
        format: '54687687',
        crop: true
         }]
}
```

Example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/levra/kmefL0tr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is not supported by default in Highcharts, but in the `afterDrawDataLabels` event, by using `css` method, you can set `textOverflow: 'ellipsis'` and the right `width` styles:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.addEvent(H.Series, 'afterDrawDataLabels', function() {
    var movement;

    this.points.forEach(function(p) {
        if (p.shapeArgs.width < p.dataLabels[0].width) {
            movement = (p.dataLabels[0].width - p.shapeArgs.width) / 2;

            p.dataLabels[0].css({
                width: p.shapeArgs.width,
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
            });
            p.dataLabels[0].text.attr({
                x: movement
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h3fwxjb7/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css